# Unexpected behavior of Series

Tags: series-expansion

I noticed something strange today. Consider the code

```
Series[x + x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

This of course outputs the usual series cut of at the second power of x. If I run instead

```
Series[x + x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I get the series untill x, but if I run

```
Series[x + x^2, {x, 0, 0}]
```

I again get the series until the *first* power of x instead of 0, which is what I would have guessed I should obtain. How can I force this behavior?

Comment: MMA 11.0.1 evaluates `{O[x], x + O[x]^2 , x + x^2 + O[x]^3}` for the different orders `{0,1,2}`, seems to be ok I think!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann my version 11.1.1.0 does not. I am trying code that I wrote on another version that did work and doesn't here. That's how I noticed

Comment: What if you directly evaluate `x + x^2 + O[x]`?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive I don't get what you mean

Comment: Copy `x + x^2 + O[x]`, paste it on your *Mathematica* notebook, and evaluate it. You can also type it in if you wish.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive  I am gonna guess you mean to run Evaluate[x + x^2 + O[x]] (I am not familiar with this command). The output is O[x]^1

Comment: Both MMA 10.2.0 and 7.0.1 also evaluate {O[x], x + O[x]^2 , x + x^2 + O[x]^3} for the different orders {0,1,2}, seems to be ok I think!